# Using a private Docker Image from Gitlab Registry as the base image for CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

How should I authenticate if I want to use an image from the Gitlab Registry as a base image of another CI build?

According to https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md#using-a-private-docker-registry I first have to manually login on the runner machine. Somehow it feels strange to login with an existing Gitlab user.

Is there a way to use the CI variable "CI_BUILD_TOKEN" (which is described as "Token used for authenticating with the GitLab Container Registry") for authentication to pull the base image from Gitlab Registry?

EDIT: I found out that I can use images from public projects. But I don't really want to make my docker projects public.

UPDATE: Starting with Gitlab 8.14 you can just use the docker images from the build in docker registry. See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md#support-for-gitlab-integrated-registry

Comment: The last link gives me not found error!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is currently not possible in any elegant way. GitLab should implement explicit credentials for the base images, it will be the most straight-forward and correct solution.

You need to `docker login` on the GitLab Runner machine. You can't use the `gitlab-ci-token` since they expire and also project-dependant, so you can't actually use one token for every project. Using your own login is pretty much the only solution available right now (happy to get corrected on this one).

Comment: Thanks. You're right. It's not possible right now. Pointers I found: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/19219 and https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/19275

Comment: To follow up on this, there are a couple gitlab tickets related to exposing this functionality in a more elegant way (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/19275). However, this appears to sit in backlog right now. Hopefully, with more support, this capability will be something that the team identifies to be as important as the user community seems to.

Answer (score 23):

### **All of the above answers including the acepted one are deprecated, This is possible in 2021:**

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#access-an-image-from-a-private-container-registry

---

### **TL;DR**

Set the CI/CD variable `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` value with appropriate authentication information in following format:

Step 1:

```
# The use of "-n" - prevents encoding a newline in the password.
echo -n "my_username:my_password" | base64

# Example output to copy
bXlfdXNlcm5hbWU6bXlfcGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

Step 2 (This JSON is the value to be set for `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` variable):

```
{
    "auths": {
        "registry.example.com:5000": {
            "auth": "(Base64 content from above)"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Now it's possible, they have included that option months ago.

Use `gitlab-ci-token`as user and the variable `$CI_BUILD_TOKEN` as password.

This example works on GitLab 8.13.6. It builds the test image if needed, and in the next stage uses it to perform syntax checks:

```
build_test:
  stage: build_test_image
  script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:test -f dockerfiles/test/Dockerfile .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:test
  tags:
    - docker_build
  environment: test

test_syntax:
  image: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:test
  stage: test
  script:
    - flake8 --ignore=E501,E265,E402 .
```

UPDATE: Re-reading the question, the accepted answer is correct. In my example, the job `test_syntax` will fail to authenticate to the registry, unless the user logins manually from the runner machine. Although, it can work if the 2 runners are on the same host, but it's not the best solution anyway.

In [gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.8](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner) there's an option to add the Registry credentials as a variable, so you only need to login once to get the encoded credentials. See [documentation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/1-8-stable/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md#using-a-private-container-registry).

Comment: What type of runner are you using to do this? If you're using a shell runner then GitLab CI isn't pulling the image from the registry but is instead using the image you just built on the host in the previous stage.

Comment: Actually I'm using 2 runners. One with shell executor, another with docker executor. The intended usage of the shell executor is only to build Docker images, that's why I'm using the tag `docker_build`. Note also the `image` directive inside the job `test_syntax` and the lack of it on `build_test`.

Answer (score 4):

This is absolutely possible as of September 2018. I'll post my naive implementation here.

## Context:

- You'll need to leverage the `docker:dind` service, which lets you run the `docker` command inside of a docker container.
- This will require you to use a valid `docker login`, which you can do using GitLab's builtin variables (`gitlab-ci-token`, `$CI-JOB-TOKEN`).
- You should then be able to authenticate to your repo's registry (example `$REGISTRY` value: `registry.gitlab.com/$USER/$REPO:$TAG`), which will allow you to push or pull docker containers from inside the CI/CD context, as well as from any authenticated docker server.

## Implementation:

Create this block at top level to ensure it runs before the following jobs:

```yaml
before_script: 
        - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $REGISTRY
```

Job to build and save images to your registry:

```yaml
build_container:
    image: docker:latest
    stage: build
    services:
        - docker:dind
    script:
        - docker build -t $REGISTRY .
        - docker push $REGISTRY
```

Job that uses the custom image:

```yaml
build_app:
    image: $REGISTRY
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - npm run build
```

## Regarding Cross-Repo Jobs:

I accomplish this by creating a "bot" GitLab user and assigning them access to repos/groups as appropriate. Then it's just a matter of replacing `gitlab-ci-token` and `$CI_JOB_TOKEN` with appropriate environment variables. This is only necessary if the base image is private.

Comment: before_script doesn't run "before" the job. It is simply concatenated with the script element, and run in the context of the image specified in the job. Given that, this doesn't look like it will work?

Comment: I'm usually using the `before_script` within an extended job so that it can be shared with multiple other docker jobs (one each for push to gitlab/dockerhub/etc., depending on tag/branch).

It's intended to be run within the context of the image and leveraging the `dind` service, as the image needs to have access to docker commands for any of `login`, `build`, `push` to work. As long as the `login` comes first, this all works as intended.

I use this strategy for multiple production applications; if you're having a specific problem I can try to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible you first have to login to gitlab container registry of the image you want to use, kindly see below example. Notice the
`before_script:` which basically auths you before using the image.

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build

variables:
  CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/obonyojimmy/node-mono-clr:latest

before_script:
  - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com

build-app:
  stage: build
  image: $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE
  script:
    - npm run build
```

Comment: docker will throw an error unless you add "$": $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation. My Java application uses Testcontainers lib in tests and this lib runs Docker container from private registry. I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and I managed to handle this by creating a `~/.docker/config.json` file in `before_script` section. I hope it'll help somebody:

```
image: openjdk:11-jdk-slim

stages:
  - build

before_script:
  - mkdir ~/".docker"
  - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$REGISTRY_HOST\":{\"auth\":\"$(printf "$REGISTRY_USER:$REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | openssl base64 -A)\"}}}" > ~/".docker/config.json"

build:
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - ./gradlew build
```