# Gitlab CI: Authentication to another project's container registry fails

Tags: docker, authentication, gitlab-ci

In my current gitlab repo ("gneh") CI, I am trying to use a docker image from another gitlab repo ("ml-v3")'s container registry.
Following [this explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70293080/19918448), as well as gitlab documentation, I have set the `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` CI variable : first to "my_username:my_password" then to "oauth2accesstoken:my_token" (both converted to base64). But in all cases, I get the following error when the pipeline runs:

```
ERROR: Job failed: failed to pull image "registry.gitlab.com/magyar_57/ml-v3:3.10" with specified policies [always]: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/magyar_57/ml-v3/manifests/3.10: unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password. See https://gitlab.com/help/user/profile/account/two_factor_authentication#troubleshooting (manager.go:237:0s)
```

2FA is not enabled on my account. And if it was, the access token should work.

I tried with a public repo, and the image is pulled correctly, so the issue is for sure at authentication. Any idea why I cannot login ?